# ibatis throwing NullPointerException

Tags: ibatis

I am trying to test iBATIS with DB. I get a NullPointerException. Below are the class and iBATIS bean config,

```
  <select id="getByWorkplaceId"
  parameterClass="java.lang.Integer" resultMap="result">
  select * from WorkDetails where workplaceCode=#workplaceCode#
  </select>

  <select id="getWorkplace" resultClass="com.ibatis.text.WorkDetails">
  select * from WorkDetails
  </select>
```

**POJO**

```
public class WorkplaceDetail implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6760386803958725272L;
private int code;
private String plant;
private String compRegNum;
private String numOfEmps;
private String typeIndst;
private String typeProd;    
private String note1;
private String note2;
private String note3;
private String note4;
private String note5;       
}
```

**DAOimplementation**

```
public class WorkplaceDetailImpl implements WorkplaceDetailsDAO {

private SqlMapClient sqlMapClient;

public void setSqlMapClient(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient) {
    this.sqlMapClient = sqlMapClient; 
    }

@Override
public WorkplaceDetail getWorkplaceDetail(int code) {
    WorkplaceDetail workplaceDetail=new WorkplaceDetail();
    try{
            **workplaceDetail= (WorkplaceDetail) this.sqlMapClient.queryForObject("workplaceDetail.getByWorkplaceId", code);**


    }catch (SQLException sqlex){
        sqlex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return workplaceDetail;
}
```

**TestCode**

```
public class TestDAO {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    WorkplaceDetail wd = new WorkplaceDetail(126, "Hoonkee", "1234", "22", "Service", "Tele", "hsgd","hsgd","hsgd","hsgd","hsgd");

    WorkplaceDetailImpl impl= new WorkplaceDetailImpl();
    **impl.getWorkplaceDetail(wd.getCode());**
    impl.saveOrUpdateWorkplaceDetails(wd);
    System.out.println("dhsd"+impl);


}
}
```

I want to select and insert. I have marked as ** ** as a point of exception in above code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibatis.text.WorkplaceDetailImpl.getWorkplaceDetail(WorkplaceDetailImpl.java:19)
at com.ibatis.text.TestDAO.main(TestDAO.java:11)
```

Comment: What does WorkplaceDetailImpl.getWorkplaceDetail look like?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post your resolution.

Comment: i don know where to accept the answer... please guide me...

Comment: @PrashantP If you managed to solve your problem, could you please add an answer of your own explaining how you solved it? You can then even accept your own answer so it's clear to all of us that the problem is solved and how.

Comment: can you please update your answer. because i'm facing same issue with my code